# Application's UI freezes when lots of stanzas are received

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, xmppframework

I am developing a chat application using Robbiehanson's XMPPFramework, when my app receives lots of stanzas, the app's UI freezes, this is how I'm making my stream.

App's UI mostly freezes when the framework attempts to send receipts against a received message or when stream manager attempts to send acknowledgements against a received stanza.

This is how I am setting up my stream.

//Stream Setup

```
if (!self.xmppStream || ![self.xmppStream isConnected]) {
    self.xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
     [self.xmppStream setHostName:kGetChatServerURLString];
    // [self.xmppStream setHostPort:kBPChatServerPort];

    [self.xmppStream setHostPort:kBPChatServerPort];
    [self.xmppStream setStartTLSPolicy:XMPPStreamStartTLSPolicyAllowed];
    self.xmppReconnect = [ [XMPPReconnect alloc] init];
    [self.xmppReconnect setAutoReconnect:YES];

    self.xmppRosterMemStorage = [[XMPPRosterMemoryStorage alloc] init];
    self.xmppRoster = [[XMPPRoster alloc] initWithRosterStorage:self.xmppRosterMemStorage dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    self.xmppRoster.autoAcceptKnownPresenceSubscriptionRequests = true;
    self.xmppRoster.autoFetchRoster = true;
    [self.xmppRoster activate:self.xmppStream];

    self.xmppMUC = [[XMPPMUC alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:_backgroundQueue];
    [self.xmppMUC activate:self.xmppStream];

    // To enable socket in the background.
    [self.xmppStream setEnableBackgroundingOnSocket:YES];

    // Moved the function to here from DidConnect to fix multiple delivery reports sending issue after reconnect.
    [self setupAutoSendDeliveryReceipts];

    XMPPMessageCarbons *xmppMessageCarbon  = [[XMPPMessageCarbons alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:_backgroundQueue];

    [xmppMessageCarbon activate:self.xmppStream];
    [xmppMessageCarbon setAutoEnableMessageCarbons:YES];

    //XEP-0191: Blocking Command
    self.xmppBlocking = [[XMPPBlocking alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:_backgroundQueue];
    [self.xmppBlocking activate:self.xmppStream];

    [self.xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:_backgroundQueue];
    [self.xmppReconnect addDelegate:self delegateQueue:_backgroundQueue];
    [self.xmppRoster addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [self.xmppMUC addDelegate:self delegateQueue:_backgroundQueue];
    [self.xmppBlocking addDelegate:self delegateQueue:_backgroundQueue];

    [[BPCXMPPvCardStorageManager sharedInstance] activateWithStream:self.xmppStream];
    [[BPCChatRoomsManager sharedManager] activateWithStream:self.xmppStream];
}
```

//Setup Stream Manager

```
- (void)setupStreamManagement {

if (kBPCTempEnableStreamManagement) {

    //Intialize with XMPPStreamManagementMemoryStorage
    XMPPStreamManagementMemoryStorage *xmppSMMS = [[XMPPStreamManagementMemoryStorage alloc] init];
    self.xmppStreamManagement = [[XMPPStreamManagement alloc] initWithStorage:xmppSMMS dispatchQueue:_backgroundQueue];

    //Activate with stream
    [self.xmppStreamManagement activate:self.xmppStream];
    self.xmppStreamManagement.autoResume = YES;
    [self.xmppStreamManagement enableStreamManagementWithResumption:YES maxTimeout:0];
    [self.xmppStreamManagement requestAck];
    [self.xmppStreamManagement sendAck];
    [self.xmppStreamManagement automaticallySendAcksAfterStanzaCount:1 orTimeout:0];
}
}
```

//Enable auto Message deliveries

```
XMPPMessageDeliveryReceipts *xmppMessageDeliveryReceipts = [[XMPPMessageDeliveryReceipts alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:dispatch_queue_create("messageDeliverReceiptsQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)];
xmppMessageDeliveryReceipts.autoSendMessageDeliveryReceipts = YES;
xmppMessageDeliveryReceipts.autoSendMessageDeliveryRequests = YES;
[xmppMessageDeliveryReceipts activate:self.xmppStream];
```

The background queue that I am using is:

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: `sendAck` is not needed if `automaticallySendAcksAfterStanzaCount` is used.

Answer (score 1):

When you get called back from the Framework with some data that triggers a UI update, which thread are you executing in?

It needs to be Thread 1 because UIKit can only run on the main thread. If it's not the main thread, you have to dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^block()); and call UIKit (aka ALL UI calls) from the block. I've learned this one the hard way, and yeah, the UI gets very sluggish and behaves very weird.

Answer (score 0):

If UI freezes its clearly meaning is your some work is going on main thread. You have to look for your task that is running in main thread. And write that chunk of code in background thread and when it completes its task then switch to main thread to update UI.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
//Background Thread
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    //Run UI Updates
});
});
```

Comment: Nothing is being done on main queue, when the framework attempt to send out stanzas or receive, it freezes the UI.

Comment: @ZeeshanAnjum What makes you dismiss that so easily? Usually a freezing UI is *the* indication for too much work on the main queue? I don't know the XMPPFramework, but surely at some point you hand over data to your main thread for UI processing, right? I can even see you set a delegate queue as the main queue in your code above. I can't give you an answer, unfortunately, and can see this one doesn't help you much, but simply denying the obvious won't help you either. At least explain what else you think even *can* freeze the UI besides a blocked main queue...

Comment: That's what I couldn't figure out, all my db operations are done on background context, which cannot obviously block the UI. I believe resources are exhausted, due to which UI freezes?

Answer (score 0):

First I'd check what's going on the main thread during the freeze.

1. Run the app in debug session through Xcode.
2. When the UI freezes, click the "pause" button in the debugging toolbar.
3. Check the call stack of the main thread/(main queue thread). You should see what function is causing the freeze and who called it.

Even if you're confident that your code runs on proper queues/threads, it's possible that the library you're using explicitly dispatches to the main queue. This happened to me before.